# Looking for a tragic cartoon short about a robot cat seen on British TV in the 80s

Tags: story-identification, robots, anime, animation

A cartoon I saw as a child in the 80s on British TV made a huge impression on me, but I've never been able to track it down online. It was a one-off short about a scientist who creates a robotic black cat. The cat falls in love with the image of a neon sign in the shape of a white kitten drinking milk, but when he climbs to embrace it, it electrocutes him and he dies. The end!

Some of the tropes remind me of Tezuka but I haven't managed to identify it. It seemed to be a one-off short rather than a series, and could easily have been American, Japanese or European.

Comment: Which channel did you see it on? If it was shown as part of children BBC for example it should be possible to track it down through old TV listings. Also what time of year? Christmas? Easter? Was it a 5 minute short or something feature length? Also did it have dialogue or not?

Comment: I believe it was shown during the daytime rather than on the 80s children's BBC after-school slot. It was quite common then for cartoons to be shown outside of that slot, presumably to amuse kids who weren't yet at school. It definitely wasn't feature-length — if it was a Western animation, I expect it must have been a 7 minute cartoon. I was very young so couldn't tell you the time of year.